# Django render_to_string behavior

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have following HTML file template.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}You have following email: {{ request.user.email }}.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

Now in python:

```
if request.user is not None and request.user.is_authenticated():
   text = render_to_string('template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request)))
```

But request.user.email is empty in template. Even if I write `{{ user.email }}`, it is still empty.
How can I render user and invoke its methods correctly?
For example, `{{ request.user.get_short_name }}` also doesn't work.

UPDATE:
The issue was with `{% blocktrans %}`

```
<p>You have following email: {{ request.user.email }}.</p>
```

Can somebody tell why?
I don't have translation messages yet, but I thought that it will render as it is.

Comment: check that `django.core.context_processors.request` is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting (it's not by default) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is there by default which ought to make `user.email` possible

Comment: These processors are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented, you can't directly use template expressions inside a `{% blocktrans %}`, only variables :

> To translate a template expression – say, accessing object attributes
>   or using template filters – you need to bind the expression to a local
>   variable for use within the translation block. Examples:

```
{% blocktrans with amount=article.price %}
That will cost $ {{ amount }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag

So your template code should looks like:

```
{% load i18n %}
<p>
{% blocktrans with email=request.user.email %}
 You have following email: {{ email }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
</p>
```